# SQL Subquery with partition and date comparison

Tags: sql, subquery, partition

have a table of where each row has an identifier (CS#) and a date.  There can multiple rows of a CS# with different dates,  Need to find the latest date and then select those that are over 6 months old.  This is being done one MS SQL Server

Trying to do this with a select within a select, but having issues

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.CS_Number,  c.CS_Name, Address, City, ZIP, Google_Maps, c.District_Email, 
      MAX(Inspection_Date) OVER (Partition BY i.CS_Number  ) 
      AS Last_Inspection 
      FROM dbo.Comfort_Station_Table c 
      LEFT JOIN dbo.CS_Inspection_Table i ON c.CS_Number = i.CS_Number 
            WHERE c.CS_Number < 9997 and c.Status = 'Open';
```

tried adding a where condition to compare `Inspection_Date < DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()) - 6, 0)`

Sample Data"

```
CS_Number   Inspection Date
1   5/13/2019 0:00
1   9/3/2019 0:00
2   5/13/2019 0:00
4   8/11/2019 0:00
7   5/25/2017 0:00
7   4/5/2019 0:00
10  11/6/2018 0:00
12  11/1/2018 0:00
13  1/4/2016 0:00
13  1/4/2019 0:00
15  6/5/2019 0:00
```

Comment: `Need to find the latest date and then select those that are over 6 months old. ` ... can you add sample data to your question which explains what this means?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?  (Note this is for DB2 but in sql server you would use datadadd and getdate())

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT i.CS_Number,  c.CS_Name, Address, City, ZIP, Google_Maps,
       c.District_Email, 
       MAX(Inspection_Date) OVER (Partition BY i.CS_Number  ) AS Last_Inspection 
    FROM dbo.Comfort_Station_Table c 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.CS_Inspection_Table i ON c.CS_Number = i.CS_Number 
    WHERE c.CS_Number < 9997 and c.Status = 'Open'
 ) X
 WHERE last_inspection < current date - 6 months
```

Comment: That does it.  Replaced the current date with my DATEADD function.

Comment: @joe glad to help -- welcome to the site -- here if an answer helps you please vote up.  If it solves your problem you can also accept the answer by clicking on the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the qualified CS_Number first by a cte or subquery and then join Comfort_Station_Table  with it:

```
  ;WITH cteLastDate(CS_Number, LastInspectionDate)
    AS
    (
      SELECT c.CS_Number,MAX(i.Inspection_Date)
      FROM dbo.Comfort_Station_Table c 
      INNER JOIN dbo.CS_Inspection_Table i ON c.CS_Number = i.CS_Number 
      WHERE c.CS_Number < 9997 and c.Status = 'Open'
      GROUP BY c.CS_Number 
      HAVING MAX(Inspection_Date) < DATEADD(MONTH,-6,GETDATE())
    )

    SELECT c.CS_Number,  c.CS_Name, Address, City, ZIP, Google_Maps, c.District_Email, 
          c.LastInspectionDate Last_Inspection 
    FROM dbo.Comfort_Station_Table c 
    INNER JOIN cteLastDate i ON c.CS_Number = i.CS_Number
```